# Behat: Cannot kill web server process when done testing

Tags: php, behat

I'm testing a web crawler script. I'm using the php builtin webserver to test against pages locally.

I can start the server but I cannot kill the process because it is already killed (I get the exception that I set `Could not kill the testing web server`).

Here is my attempt:

```
<?php

use Behat\Behat\Tester\Exception\PendingException;
use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
use Behat\Behat\Context\SnippetAcceptingContext;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\PyStringNode;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\TableNode;

use Behat\Behat\Hook\Scope\BeforeScenarioScope;
use Behat\Behat\Hook\Scope\AfterScenarioScope;

/**
 * Defines application features from the specific context.
 */
class FeatureContext implements Context, SnippetAcceptingContext
{

    const TESTING_BASE_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:6666';
    const TESTING_DIR = '/tmp/testDirectory';

    private $pid;

    /**
     * Initializes context.
     *
     * Every scenario gets its own context instance.
     * You can also pass arbitrary arguments to the
     * context constructor through behat.yml.
     */
     public function __construct()
     {
     }

    /**
     * @BeforeScenario
     */
    public function before(BeforeScenarioScope $scope)
    {
        // Create testing directory holding our pages
        if (!is_dir(self::TESTING_DIR)) {
            if (!mkdir(self::TESTING_DIR)) {
                throw new \Exception('Cannot create the directory for testing');
            }
        }

        // Start the testing server
        $command = sprintf(
            'php -S %s -t $%s >/dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!',
            escapeshellarg(self::TESTING_BASE_URL),
            escapeshellarg(self::TESTING_DIR)
        );

        $output = [];
        exec($command, $output, $return_var);

        if ($return_var !== 0) {
            throw new \Exception('Cannot start the testing web server');
        }

        $this->pid = (int)$output[0];
        echo sprintf(
            'Testing web server started on %s with PID %s %s %s',
            self::TESTING_BASE_URL,
            (string)$this->pid,
            PHP_EOL,
            PHP_EOL
        );

    }

    /**
     * @AfterScenario
     */
    public function after(AfterScenarioScope $scope)
    {
          // ... kill the web server
          $output = [];
          exec('kill ' . (string) $this->pid, $return_var);

          if ($return_var !== 0) {
              throw new \Exception('Could not kill the testing web server (PID ' . (string) $this->pid . ')');
          }

          echo 'Testing web server killed (PID ', (string) $this->pid, ')', PHP_EOL, PHP_EOL;

          // ... remove the test directory
          $o = [];
          exec('rm -rf ' . escapeshellarg(self::TESTING_DIR), $o, $returnVar);

          if ($returnVar !== 0) {
              throw new \Exception('Cannot remove the testing directory');
          }
    }


    // ...
}
```

I also tried various things like putting it all in the constructor, using `register_shutdown_function`, without any success.

What am I missing? Any idea on how I can solve this?

Instead of just "not caring about killing the server process" (because to me it looks like it's gone when I try to kill the process, hence the error, I can't find it when I issue `ps aux | grep php` on the command line after running behat), isn't it "cleaner" to kill it as I attend to?

Answer (score 0):

The exec call is missing the output parameter:

```
exec('kill ' . (string) $this->pid, $output, $return_var);
```

Unless this is set, the exception will always be thrown, because `$return_var` is actually the output of the command (which is an array not an integer).